# Is bonds in CO is all 3 coordinate bonds or 2 covalent and 1 coordinate bonds?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure, lewis-structure, valence-bond-theory

Below image is as available in India's Class 11 NCERT Chemistry book vol 1 Page 104. I am confused as it states all 3 bonds are kind of coordinate bonds. Should it not start with 2 covalent bonds and 3rd as coordinate bond from oxygen to satisfy carbon? There are several sites confirming my expectation. This book is in a place to force students to study and repeat in exams to get marks. So wondering does it get this right? or teaching wrong?

[image]

Comment: You cannot distinguish these kinds of bonds. The total bonding between the partner atoms can be seen on a spectra from covalent to ionic, but interpreting that is not without bias. In any case, the final structure in your screenshot is wrong, it is missing the formal charges.

Comment: This^ is just some drawing dot formulas for beginners and doesn't imply anything like that.